# remote machine browser access using VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I have installed **VScode** in the 'windows' machine but connected remote Linux machine with VScode extension(SSH) help.
Whenever I build code in windows VScode IDE, I have to access "http://localhost:4200/" in the Linux browser, but I want to open the same link in the windows browser by "http://linuxMachineIP:4200/", It's not working.

What is the efficient way of using remote machine browser from local machine, Please help :)

Comment: F1 -> Forward a Port